# What are the different way to check click event of shape in kendo diagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo diagram in that shapes are there, i have to recognize which shape is click.

I have done some code using below logic, but its not working properly after implementing in my requirement.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='diagram'></div>
<script>
  $("#diagram").kendoDiagram({
    shapes: [
      {
        id: "1",
        content: {
          text: "Monday"
        }
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        content:{
          text:"Tuesday"
        }
      }
    ],
    connections: [

      {
        from: "1",
        to: "2"
      }
    ],
    layout: {
      type: "tree"
    },
    click: function(e) {
      if(e.item instanceof kendo.dataviz.diagram.Shape)
        alert(e.item.options.content? e.item.options.content.text: "No content.");
      else
        alert("Shape not clicked");
    },
    shapeDefaults: {
      type: "circle",
      width: 70,
      height: 70,
      hover: {
        fill: "Orange"
      }
    },
    connectionDefaults: {
      type: "polyline",
      startCap: "FilledCircle",
      endCap: "ArrowEnd"
    }
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the click event if condition is there, that condition is getting true first time only if i implement code in my requirement, It must be true in each click of shape. If there is another way to check the click part is shape please do mention.

Comment: For me is showing the alert every time I click the shape with the right content!? When I click the arrow is getting the else condition. Can´t see any problem here

Comment: @FrozenButcher there no problem in that code, as i mentioned in Question after implementing that code as per my requirement after that first time only click is working, What actually I am doing means after first click i am catching the text of that shape and i will redirect to the another page in my project and where i will some small operation and will come back to this kendo diagram page again now After coming back to here everytime only else part will get execute. Hope u understand what i want to say.

Comment: Well, I did not :-) @TauFeeQ why don´t you post the code implemented with your requirement?

Comment: @FrozenButcher bro its too complicated. it  has many file dependencies thats y, Well plz consider above file is file 1, after clicking on shape i will redirect to the file 2, in file 2 I  will click on a go back button then again i will come back to the file 1, and now it will execute the else block only whether i click on connection or shape. Got it.?

Comment: Send a url parameter from the 2nd page when you link back. Read this parameter value when the 1st page is loading, include the value on your if condition.

Comment: Thank u very much  @FrozenButcher i got that, I am rendering that diagram then Its working.